# Google Analytics don't get my data from my app

Tags: java, android, xml, google-analytics

I'll to use Google Analytic to get more data as Google Play presents. I've all made like the tutorial says:
[Google Guides](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/)

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    // The rest of your onStart() code.
    EasyTracker.getInstance(this).activityStart(this);  // Add this method.

}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    // The rest of your onStop() code.
    EasyTracker.getInstance(this).activityStop(this);  // Add this method.
}
```

analytics.xml *id replaced with ###*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
    <!--Replace placeholder ID with your tracking ID-->
    <string name="ga_trackingId">UA-###-1</string>
    <!--Enable automatic activity tracking-->
    <bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true</bool>
    <!--Enable automatic exception tracking-->
    <bool name="ga_reportUncaughtExceptions">true</bool>
    <integer name="ga_dispatchPeriod">15</integer>
</resources>
```

manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: where did you added the app id ?

Comment: maybe I missed that - how to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your `analytics.xml` with the `tracking ID` of your app like following,

```
    <string name="ga_trackingId">UA-48673260-1</string>
```

Comment: oh this I have done; sorry I missunderstood - I've just replaced it with "###"

Comment: no :( - I've also reload the google a. page very often and nothing happens...; I've just replaced it for here

Comment: Have you taken the permissions required ?